# convert decimal that is less than 1024 into two variable one with 8 bits and other with 2 using C

Tags: c, microcontroller, mikroc

hi I'm programming a microcontroller using MikroC, and I have this variable which is less than 1024 (2^10bit) and I needed to convert that `int value;` to `unsigned char value8bits;` and put the least significant bits in the `unsigned char value2bits;`

I was actually thinking of using >> bit shifting don't know how yet? so what do you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
10bitvar = 956;

8bitvar = (10bitvar >> 2) & 0xff;
2bitvar = (10bitvar & 0x03);



10bitvar        =    1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
(10bitvar >> 2) =    ? ? 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
    &                    & & & & & & & &
  0xff          =        1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      
                        ----------------
8bitvar                  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1


10bitvar        =    1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
    &                    & & & & & & & &
  0x03          =        0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1      
                        ----------------
2bitvar                  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```